# Java sql update error : data type mismatch

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I have created a table in ms access. I have set the data type of ID to Auto Number in MS-access. In java when I try to update a record. the netBeans IDE gives me the error of " data type missmatch in criteria expression".
But when I changed the ID number that was not in the table already it works well. The code is below.

```
String sql = "Update table1 set price ='" + txtPrice.getText() + "', quantity='" + txtQuantity.getText() + "', description='" + txtDescription.getText() + "' where id= " + txtid.getText() + "";
        try {
             pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
            UpdateJTable();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Comment: It's good to post the stacktrace, if you are receiving error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing a regular Statement and PreparedStatement objects, too.  PreparedStatement gives you the opportunity to use placeholders (the ? you might see in a lot of sql statements) and let the PreparedStatement do a bit more work for you.

Try writing your sql statement like this:

```
update table1 set price = ?, quantity = ?, description = ? where id = ?
```

Then with your PreparedStatement object, you would do:

```
pStmt.setInteger(1, Integer.valueOf(txtPrice.getText())
```

for each parameter.  It has been a few years since I used PreparedStatement directly, but if memory serves, parameters are 1-based.

But your basic problem is one of casting.  It also might make your code cleaner (and more secure) to use a PreparedStatement for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `price` and `quantity` columns are integers, hence you dont need to quote them.

Try the following sql:

```
String sql = "Update table1 set price =" + txtPrice.getText() + ",
              quantity=" + txtQuantity.getText() + ", description='" +
              txtDescription.getText() + "' where id= " + txtid.getText() + "";
```

Note the single-quotes are missing from price and quantity

Comment: Suraj chandran there is another error after doing that the error is of "Too few parameters" no whats this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the type casting in your id field first. like:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText());
```

Then execute query :

```
String sql = "Update table1 set price ='" + txtPrice.getText() + "', quantity='" +
              txtQuantity.getText() + "', description='" + txtDescription.getText() + "' 
              where id= " + id + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

for the too few parameters error that you are getting - double check the field names in you query.